# Python (PyGame)

Tags: python, file

I have to make a game on PyGame but do all the coding on python and I am getting an invalid syntax error on this code:

```
finally:
    print "The game was closed."
    pygame.quit ()
    quit()
```

And, this is the error I am getting on the line where it says finally:

```
Python Shell, prompt 1, line 110
invalid syntax: <string>, line 110, pos 7
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: you code is just 4 line ?? please give us complete code or part of it

Comment: What is the content of line 110?  Is line 110 in the code block you have provided above?

Comment: Also, what version of python are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Finally follows an if or try loop. 
It is not needed as you can just put the code inline below, allowing it to execute normally after said process has completed.

Remove the finally and fix the whitespace.

```
print "The game was closed."
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Also if for some reason you are using python 3 , print is a function, so add brackets around the string. Don't forget to fix the whitespace also here!

```
print("The game was closed.")
```